# How can I increase the final integer variable?

Tags: java, android, final

Eclipse is offering `final` but I can't increase the `i` variable.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSayac);

    int i = 1;
    do {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (i < 16);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not letting you do that since it would be racy.

Comment: When you call `setText()`, what are you expecting to get set - the real-time current value of `i`, or the value of `i` at the time the thread was created?

Comment: Also, why are you creating a `Thread` within a `Thread` and not even starting the outside one?

Comment: @downvoter: What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A final is an entity that can not be changed after it is initialized.

[Final (Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)

What you could do is create a variable within the scope of the do/while loop that is final with the value of `i` and send that into the function.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution here is to create a class:

```
public class FinalCounter {

    private int val;

    public FinalCounter(int intialVal) {
        val=intialVal;
    }
    public void increment(){
        val++;
    }
    public void decrement(){
        val--;
    }
    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        final FinalCounter test = new FinalCounter(0);
        test.increment(); // 1
        test.increment(); // 2
        test.increment(); // 3
        test.increment(); // 4
        test.increment(); // 5
        test.decrement(); // 4
        System.out.println(test.getVal());  // prints 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible to create a local copy of the variable `i`. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSayac);

    int i = 1;
    do {
        final int localCopy = i; // Create here a final copy of i
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    tv.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // use here the copy
                            tv.setText(Integer.toString(localCopy));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start(); // Don't forget to start the Thread!
            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (i < 16);
}
```

By creating a final local copy:

- the compiler won't complain anymore
- because of Java copies by value, you will only increase `i` and not `localCopy`.

I suppose you want to start the Thread as well...

EDIT: Indeed, you were right. You have to create the local final copy inside the loop. Check the new code.

Comment: when I paste your code to eclipse, it generated same error on the line where `localCopy` is declared :(

Comment: `final int localCopy = i; // Create here a final copy of i` this line is generating an error like `i must be defined as final` .

Comment: @uzay95: Did you move the line, like I did?

Answer (score 1):

A final variable can only be initialized once not necessarily when you are  defining it. It can be set any time within the constructor , but only once. In your case when you are incrementing i using i++, you are trying to assign the incremented value to i again which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a counter class [like that](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/ap/subset/code/Counter.html) and increment it. This way, the reference of the Counter object could be final but you could still set its value ?

Comment: -1: This won't work. Because you are working with a reference to the `myCounter` variable, which changes. The result will be that all the composed String will be the same. Create a local copy of the counter in the counter class, and I will +1.

Comment: Sorry but i dont get your point. Declaring an instance final doesnt make its fields final, so why would we have all the strings identicals?

Comment: You will have only one instance of the Counter class. You are using the reference to the instance inside the Thread body, which will be executed later. The loop creates a Thread and increases the counter. And when the Thread is finally running (when the loop is done), the counter will be `16` (break condition of the loop).

Comment: Check this pastebin. I wrote both, the way you suggest and the way I did: http://pastebin.com/0Stw5a1n

Comment: Actually Sephy's suggestion was what I needed in my case (which is a little different). I wanted to have multiple threads being able to read and write a single shared integer. So I used a single (final) reference to a class instance having a (non-final) integer field. The Counter class was not exactly what I needed since I wanted to set the integer value rather than incrementing it. I used an instance of the java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger class. Potential race conditions did not apply in my case, since the threads are user interface handlers.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add a:

```
private int i;
```

Before this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSayac);

    i = 1;
    do {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (i < 16);
}
```

And you'll be able to use your variable as usual after that, without having to mark it as final.